# Why does activator fail with "IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed" upon creating new play project?

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt, typesafe-activator

I am on Windows 7 with Java 8.

I'm attempting to create a new Play Framework project as follows:

```
activator new proj play-java
```

I get the exception below instead.

```
[WARN] [11/15/2014 15:41:45.884] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [ActorSystem(default)] Failed to download new template catalog properties: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Source file 'C:\Users\Joe\.activator\1.2.10\templates\index.db_f57d6c4e52990e27.tmp' is a directory.
[INFO] [11/15/2014 15:41:45.886] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://default/user/template-cache] We have index hash 92e262205ed9cd3af57575198c66ca1f74dfab63 but haven't downloaded that index - attempting to download it now.
[ERROR] [11/15/2014 15:41:46.210] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://default/user/template-cache] Could not find a template catalog. (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Source file 'C:\Users\Joe\.activator\1.2.10\templates\index.db_687dfd4721d5d98b.tmp' is a directory.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Source file 'C:\Users\Joe\.activator\1.2.10\templates\index.db_687dfd4721d5d98b.tmp' is a directory.
        at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:219)
        at sbt.IO$.copyFile(IO.scala:584)
        at sbt.IO$.move(IO.scala:786)
        at activator.package$RichIO$.createViaTemporary$extension(package.scala:30)
        at activator.templates.repository.UriRemoteTemplateRepository$$anonfun$resolveIndexTo$1.apply(UriRemoteTemplateRepository.scala:228)
        at activator.templates.repository.UriRemoteTemplateRepository$$anonfun$resolveIndexTo$1.apply(UriRemoteTemplateRepository.scala:220)
        at sbt.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:291)
        at activator.templates.repository.UriRemoteTemplateRepository.resolveIndexTo(UriRemoteTemplateRepository.scala:220)
        at activator.cache.TemplateCacheActor$$anonfun$9.apply(TemplateCacheActor.scala:165)
        at activator.cache.TemplateCacheActor$$anonfun$9.apply(TemplateCacheActor.scala:163)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Source file 'C:\Users\Joe\.activator\1.2.10\templates\index.db_687dfd472
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Source file 'C:\Users\Joe\.activator\1.2.10\templates\index.db_687dfd472        
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:245)1d5d98b.tmp' is a directory.
        at activator.cache.TemplateCacheActor.preStart(TemplateCacheActor.scala:163)
        at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:219)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundPreStart(Actor.scala:470)
        at sbt.IO$.copyFile(IO.scala:584)
        at activator.cache.TemplateCacheActor.aroundPreStart(TemplateCacheActor.scala:25)
        at sbt.IO$.move(IO.scala:786)
        at sbt.IO$.move(IO.scala:786)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:580)
        at activator.package$RichIO$.createViaTemporary$extension(package.scala:30)
        at activator.package$RichIO$.createViaTemporary$extension(package.scala:30)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:456)
        at activator.templates.repository.UriRemoteTemplateRepository$$anonfun$resolveIndexTo$1.apply(UriRemoteTemplateRepository.scala at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:478):228):228)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:263)
        at activator.templates.repository.UriRemoteTemplateRepository$$anonfun$resolveIndexTo$1.apply(UriRemoteTemplateRepository.scala at activator.templates.repository.UriRemoteTemplateRepository$$anonfun$resolveIndexTo$1.apply(UriRemoteTemplateRepository.scala at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393):220)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at sbt.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:291)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at activator.templates.repository.UriRemoteTemplateRepository.resolveIndexTo(UriRemoteTemplateRepository.scala:220)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at activator.cache.TemplateCacheActor$$anonfun$9.apply(TemplateCacheActor.scala:165)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
        at activator.cache.TemplateCacheActor$$anonfun$9.apply(TemplateCacheActor.scala:163)
        at activator.cache.TemplateCacheActor$$anonfun$9.apply(TemplateCacheActr.scala:163)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:245)
        at activator.cache.TemplateCacheActor.preStart(TemplateCacheActor.scala:163)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundPreStart(Actor.scala:470)
        at activator.cache.TemplateCacheActor.aroundPreStart(TemplateCacheActor.scala:25)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:580)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:456)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:478)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:263)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

I downloaded the full activator installation package. I updated it to make sure everything has permissions on every file. The `index.db_687dfd472` file from the stack trace is indeed a directory but it must've been created during the execution of the command. I have deleted the `.activator` project and re-run the command but it keeps failing with the same error.

It's been crossposted to activator issue tracker as https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues/785.
I will update the other site with any answer.

Comment: Can you do `activator 'reboot full'` to see if that helps? What command line client do you use - `cmd.exe` or something else like `cygwin` or `powershell`? Are you behind a proxy perhaps?

Comment: I'm using cmd.exe. No proxy. Running activator reboot full just brings up the readme text. I was able to create a project using the UI version so I can probably close this but still a strange error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr** Execute `activator 'reboot full'`.

The idea behind `reboot full` is to wipe out all of your local sbt caches and start over. It seems that the `~/.sbt` directory got damaged in a way to not let sbt run properly anymore.